# When and How to use Linking verb (Is/Was/Were) In the sentence?

Tags: linking-verbs

Which one of the below sentence is correct? Is there any rule to include linking verb?

a) Three person were killed when boat capsized due to overload.

b) Three person killed when boat was capsized due to overload.

c) Three person were killed when boat was capsized due to overload.

Answer (score 2):

> Three people were killed when a/the *(depending on the context)* boat capsized/was capsized due to an overload.

The sentence above would be correct.

We need to use the passive voice: the people **were killed** BUT they **died** (`they died` is an active voice sentence).

And **a boat capsizes** if it is overturned in the water. The active voice is correct. But the passive voice (is capsized) can also be used: if you capsize a boat, or if it capsizes, it turns upside down or onto its side in the water (Macmillan Dictionary).

Comment: @ Enguroo ...Active Voice would be *Boat is Capsized* or *Boat capsized*

Comment: @ Enguroo... How the boat capsized on its own. Capsized is transitive verb. Hence have confusion. I Think we should use passive voice.

Comment: @user4084 "capsize" can be both transitive and intransitive (https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/capsize) - if you capsize a boat, or if it capsizes, it turns upside down or onto its side in the water. "is capsized" is passive, and "capsized" is active. I have edited my answer. Have a look please.

Comment: @ Enguroo...Got it ..We can use Active or passive its our choice....Thanks